# How to Create Symfony User login using FR3DLdapBundle and FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, authentication, active-directory, ldap, fr3dldapbundle

I try to use FR3DLdapBundle and FosUserBundle for user authentication and login in my Symfony2 application.

I do not have any experiences with Active directory, LDAP and how to integrate it with Symfony2 application, I found that FR3DLdapBundle tutorial/manual is hard to understand and leak of basic information about how to use it properly.

I have set up everything based on their tutorial at https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

and I also have read their documentation but I still do not understand about how to make user login using it.

for your information :

- My Symfony version is 2.7
- Active Directory server info is metioned hore http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/
- I am on UBuntu Linux 14.04

My Question is :

- How to create user login with FR3DLdapBundle and FosUserBundle for the users that exist in ldap.forumsys.com   server (http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) ?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank's

Comment: No full solution but maybe my issue with the FOSUser command line tool helps you: https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/issues/111

Comment: now I use native php functionalities for LDAP instead of using 3rd party bundle, I think php ldap is simple stuff, we just need connect and query to server, 3rd party bundles just make the simple thing become complicated...

Comment: The symfony ldap component will be added to symfony2.8 core soon anyway! I can wait! :) https://github.com/symfony/ldap

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I'm looking at old posts....